# When I disable my touch screen, I logout automatically

Tags: touchscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. After disabling touch screen, a logout automatically happens a few seconds later.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:13                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]

xinput disable 9
```

Comment: Look like you are crashing xwayland. Please search for the 'ubuntu-bug' application on your system and use it to file a bug report against the xwayland package.

Comment: I use `xinput disable 9` to disable my touch screen on startup. I just upgraded to 17.10 from 17.04 and now if I touch my touchscreen it causes my session to logout. Maybe this is related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I finally found a solution to it. According to it you have to create a file called hid_multitouch.conf in /etc/modprobe.d.

Inside the file add the following text:

```
blacklist hid-multitouch
```

After saving it, do a reboot. That's all. The touchscreen will be disabled peermanently.